# Jquery datatable does not recognize HTML changes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am adding a some data to a column in my Jquery datatable based on on input event. The datatable column is being populated but I am populating it using Jquery doing:

```
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.string').html(value3);
```

However, when I search for this value it does not return it. Is there a way I can refresh the datatable so that it can recognize the value in the column. Or is there a way I can add value to that column in the first place so that it gets recognized?

Comment: If you change the content of the table manually, you must refresh the datatable. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [cell().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) function to update the data stored in a cell (for example) then call the [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) function to refresh the datatable data.

The search function searches a cached representation of the data, not the HTML of the rendered table, which is why using jQuery to modify the table doesn't work.